# How do I test alert pop ups in jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, alert, karma-jasmine

```
   if (BaseUtil.isEmptyString($scope.username))
    {
        alert("UserName is empty");
        return;
    }
```

So here i want to test this alert with the specific message "Username is empty" in case my $scope.username is empty.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem .

```
var window;
var controller;

 beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$window_)
      {
          $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
          window = _$window_;        
          controller = $controller("loginController", {$scope: $scope,                                                      
        }));

 it('check login credential blank user name', function() 
        {
            $scope.username = '';
            spyOn(window, 'alert')
            .....
            .......
            expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('UserName is empty');         
    });
```